# Question on perturbation theory

Tags: matrices, perturbation-theory

The Davis  Kahan theorem as stated in theorem 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2657.pdf says that the sin of the angle between the dominant eigenvector of $A$ and $A+E$ will be $\leq ||E||/\delta$, where $\delta$ is the separation between the largest and second largest eigenvalue.

How do we chose $E$ to make equality hold?